# How to get LinkedIn profile stats (views, appearance in searches) using API?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I want to display a similar graph as display in Profile Stats page of LinkedIn where you can view a graph with number profile views and number appearance in searches. Can I achieve this using the linkedin api?

Like this

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8081/8391002635_586c722eb6_o.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, profile statistics are not exposed via the LinkedIn API

Comment: Thanks, this is gonna be a problem :(